# Multiple identical named Resource-Files in a VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, msbuild

> ***Related:*** [What could cause Visual Studio / C# error MSB3105: Duplicate resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313718/what-could-cause-visual-studio-c-error-msb3105-duplicate-resources)

I'd like to have multiple identical named resource files in my project, all separated via the Namespace. The following setup:

```
Project
    - Namespace1 [also a Folder]
          - MyResourceFile.resx
    - Namespace2.SubNamespace1 [two folders]
          - MyResourceFile.resx
```

This is easily possible by setting `Namespace`-property of the resource files to the correct namespaces. Unfortunately this will bring the compiler to a halt:

> The item obj\x86\Debug\Project.MyResourceFile.resx was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter.

As it seems, Resource-Files are compiled into a file called `ProjectNameSpace.Filename.resx`, which is a problem if you want to have multiple identical named resource files in different namespaces.

Does somebody know how I can change that behavior?

The reason why I want this is because I want to store SQl-Statements in resource files. The datalayer of my application is hidden behind interfaces which allow multiple implementations, therefor I thought of the following structure:

```
Project
    - ModuleNamespace
        - IData.vb
        - Datas
            - MySQL
                - Data.vb (Implementation of IData)
                - Queries.resx
             - SQLite
                - Data.vb
                - Queries.resx
             - and so on...
```

I would have added those queries to a simple class-file and used that, but in that Project I'm using VB.NET...which adds a little pain to have a string span multiple lines...

Comment: Clearly Microsoft couldn't perceive of a good reason to store the exact same resources twice.  It is certainly quite wasteful.  I can't think of one either.  You could xcopy the .resx file in a prebuild event perhaps.

Comment: See my edit, I tried to explain why I want that.